# (Python)element at the equal interval from the end

Tags: python, list

How to get  [1,4,7] from the my_list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], which is the list of elements  at the equal interval(in this case, 3) "from the end" of the my_list?

```
my_list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
# how to get  [1,4,7] from the list above?
```

Comment: Can you explain? What does it mean *"the list of elements at the equal interval(in this case, 3) "from the end" of the my_list"*? Shouldn't it be `[1, 4, 7]`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Right, [1,4,7] should be.

Comment: Well, you should probably [edit] the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `[1,4,7]` is supposed to be the result this snipped of code should do the job

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(list(reversed(my_list[-3::-3])))
```

result

```
[1, 4, 7]
```